# TBlobField delphi equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, delphi

Is there any keyword equivalent to TBlobField(Delphi) in C#. Though we have OracleLob, we cannot convert a datacolumn directly into OracleLob, as

`OracleLob blob = (OracleLob)(dataTable["Column_Name"];`

throws error. Whereas, with the help of `.AsVariant`, in Delphi, it can be easily converted into TBlobField as,

```
TBlobField(AcctNumberCDS.FieldByName('IMAGE_BLOB'));
```

Wondering if there's any equivalent that would help as TBlobField.